# Visibility clip

Tags: eevee-render-engine, visibility

[image]

it gone when I pull out camera. Anyone pls tell me what happened here?

Comment: May be [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132036/shadow-clipped-when-zoom-out-eevee?rq=1) will help(Asked by you).

Comment: But this is not shadow. Whole object gone. Also no problem with view clip as you can see other objects beside it behave properly.

Comment: But have you tried it?

Comment: "I guess you are using a Sun lamp? Have a look at the Max Distance under the Cascaded Shadow Map." this answer solved my last question but I do not have any sun lamp and will not need any lights for now. Shadow is not my concern for now.

Comment: please upload a file containing the issue https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I got an answer after hours of searching. It's material problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be, increase your camera clipping distance!
Select your camera, go to object data and increase `End`:
[image]

Hope this helps.